# ERC721 - safeTransferFrom function reverts on called by approved address

Tags: erc-721

In ERC721, safeTransferFrom function , we run approve() to clear the approval, if any, for the tokenId being transferred.
This function can be called by owner or operator or approved address.
But for running the approve function, caller must be owner or operator.
So, if an approved address (not owner or operator) calls safeTransferFrom, then the function call reverts. How to avoid this ?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.4;

contract ERC721 {

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 indexed _tokenId);

    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _approved, uint256 _tokenId);

    event ApprovalForAll(address indexed _owner, address indexed _operator, bool _approved);

    mapping(address => uint256) internal _balances;

    mapping(uint256 => address payable) internal _owners;

    mapping(address => mapping(address => bool)) private _operatorApprovals;

    mapping(uint256 => address) private _tokenApprovals;

    // Returns the number of NFTs assigned to an owner
    function balanceOf(address payable owner) public view returns(uint256) {
        require(owner != address(0), "Address is zero");
        return _balances[owner];
    }

    // Finds the owner of an NFT
    function ownerOf(uint256 tokenId) public view returns(address payable) {
        address payable owner = _owners[tokenId];
        require(owner != address(0), "TokenID does not exist");
        return payable (owner);
    }

    // Enables or disables an operator to manage all of msg.senders assets.
    function setApprovalForAll(address operator, bool approved) public {
        _operatorApprovals[msg.sender][operator] = approved;
        emit ApprovalForAll(msg.sender, operator, approved);
    }

    // Checks if an address is an operator for another address
    function isApprovedForAll(address owner, address operator) public view returns(bool) {
        return _operatorApprovals[owner][operator];
    }

    // Updates an approved address for an NFT
    function approve(address to, uint256 tokenId) public {
        address owner = ownerOf(tokenId);
        require(msg.sender == owner || isApprovedForAll(owner, msg.sender), "Msg.sender is not the owner or an approved operator");
        _tokenApprovals[tokenId] = to;
        emit Approval(owner, to, tokenId);
    }

    // Gets the approved address for a single NFT
    function getApproved(uint256 tokenId) public view returns(address) {
        require(_owners[tokenId] != address(0), "Token ID does not exist");
        return _tokenApprovals[tokenId];
    }

    // Transfers ownership of an NFT
    function transferFrom(address from, address payable to, uint256 tokenId) public {
        address owner = ownerOf(tokenId);
        require(
            msg.sender == owner ||
            getApproved(tokenId) == msg.sender ||
            isApprovedForAll(owner, msg.sender),
            "Msg.sender is not the owner or approved for transfer"
        );
        require(owner == from, "From address is not the owner");
        require(to != address(0), "Address is zero");
        require(_owners[tokenId] != address(0), "TokenID does not exist");
        approve(address(0), tokenId);

        _balances[from] -= 1;
        _balances[to] += 1;
        _owners[tokenId] = to;

        emit Transfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    // Standard transferFrom
    // Checks if onERC721Received is implemented WHEN sending to smart contracts
    function safeTransferFrom(address from, address payable to, uint256 tokenId, bytes memory _data) public {
        transferFrom(from, to, tokenId);
        require(_checkOnERC721Received(), "Receiver not implemented");
    }

    function safeTransferFrom(address from, address payable to, uint256 tokenId) public {
        safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId, "");
    }

    // Oversimplified
    function _checkOnERC721Received() private pure returns(bool) {
        return true;
    }

    // EIP165 : Query if a contract implements another interface
    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public pure virtual returns(bool) {
        return interfaceId == 0x80ac58cd;
    }

}

contract Anime is ERC721 {

    string public nameNFT; // ERC721Metadata 

    string public symbolNFT; // ERC721Metadata

    uint256 public tokenCount; 

    mapping(uint256 => string) private _tokenURIs;

    constructor() {
        nameNFT = "anime";
        symbolNFT = "ANIME";
    }

    // Returns a URL that points to the metadata
    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) { // ERC721Metadata
        require(_owners[tokenId] != address(0), "TokenId does not exist");
        return _tokenURIs[tokenId];
    }
    
    // Creates a new NFT inside our collection
    function mintNFT(string memory _tokenURI) public {

        tokenCount += 1; // tokenId
        _balances[msg.sender] += 1;
        _owners[tokenCount] = payable(msg.sender);
        _tokenURIs[tokenCount] = _tokenURI; 

        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, tokenCount);
    }
    
    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public pure override returns(bool) {
        return interfaceId == 0x80ac58cd || interfaceId == 0x5b5e139f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code, or a link to your code, if you want us to be able to help you.

Comment: Done , Line # 47 & 70 in approve() & safeTransferFrom() to be checked, when safeTransferFrom is called by an approved (not owner or operator) address.